# How to display the value of the selected option tag when clicked AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to display the value of the option inside of select tag as soon as it is clicked/selected using ajax. I tried this code(below) but it doesn't work.

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <select name="count_pax" id="count_paxx" class="form-control col-md-9"/>
            <option value="">Select how many people</option>
            <option value="1">1 pax</option>
            <option value="2">2 pax</option>
            <option value="3">3 pax</option>
            <option value="4">4 pax</option>
            <option value="5">5 pax</option>
            <option value="6">6 pax</option>
            <option value="7">7 pax</option>
            <option value="8">8 pax</option>
            <option value="9">9 pax</option>
            <option value="10">10 pax</option>
            <option value="11">11 pax</option>
            <option value="12">12 pax</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row" id="demo_paxx">
    </div>
```

This is my ajax code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#count_paxx").change(function(){
            document.getElementById('$demo_paxx').innerHTML = $('#count_paxx option:selected').val();
        })
    });
```

Comment: `$('#count_paxx').val();` should be enough

Comment: or `document.getElementById('demo_paxx').innerHTML = $(this).val()`

Comment: What "ajax" are you referring to, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$demo_paxx` ID doesn't exist (that `$` should not be there).

Since you're using jQuery, you can:

- select it using the [ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), with `$('#demo_paxx')`,
- retrieve the selected value by using
  [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on the `select` element,
- make use of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to alter its content.

**Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#count_paxx').on('change', function() {
    $('#demo_paxx').text($(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <select name="count_pax" id="count_paxx" class="form-control col-md-9" />
  <option value="">Select how many people</option>
  <option value="1">1 pax</option>
  <option value="2">2 pax</option>
  <option value="3">3 pax</option>
  <option value="4">4 pax</option>
  <option value="5">5 pax</option>
  <option value="6">6 pax</option>
  <option value="7">7 pax</option>
  <option value="8">8 pax</option>
  <option value="9">9 pax</option>
  <option value="10">10 pax</option>
  <option value="11">11 pax</option>
  <option value="12">12 pax</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group row" id="demo_paxx">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each select item has a value, which is the selected value. You will need to lookup the value's option on change.

```
const selectElem = document.querySelector('#count_paxx');
const outputElem = document.querySelector('#demo_paxx');

selectElem.addEventListener('change', () => {
    outputElem.innerText = selectElem.querySelector(`option[value='${selectElem.value}']`).innerText
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu0onef8/)